# In gnu assembly langage (for arm64), how can I specify a variable to be placed in a specific section?

Tags: assembly, linker, arm64

In assembly code, this code

```
.data
myval : .long 0x11111111
```

places the variable `myval` in `.data` section. So I wanted to define my own section in a specific address in SDRAM and use it in the assembly code to write some data for debug. I added my section in the linker script like this (this is the first section output to .sdram so I know the starting address).

```
.mydebug : {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    KEEP(*(.__mydebug));
} >.sdram
```

and used it in the assembly code like this.

```
.global
... skip ...
mov x6, #0x70
ldr x7, =myval
str x6, [x7]
... skip ...
.__mydebug
myval: .long 0x11111111
```

But the compile complains

```
Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.__mydebug'
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.section` directive.

```
        .section .__mydebug
myval:  .long 0x11111111
```

One thing to know: custom sections should not have their name begin with a period.  Such names are reserved for sections defined by the ABI.  So perhaps call the section something like `mydebug`.  Although in contravention of the ELF specification, it is also common to use a name like `.data.mydebug` for a section that is similar to `.data` but needs to be segregated from normal data.

Comment: Nit: usually that's a good idea to start section with `align` / `balign` directive to make sure that data alignment requirements are fulfilled